# STM32 - write to SPI on first rising edge, and read on first falling edge?

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm trying to talk to another IC (a Microchip SPI flash chip) which wants to read in data on the rising edge but write it out on the falling edge using an STM32F4 series MCU.  I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955707/stm32-spi-write-on-rising-edge-and-read-on-falling-edge-possible) but the solution there doesn't seem to work (I just get nothing out of the chip).

The only configuration that causes the chip to recognize the command and respond is CPOL=1, CPHA=0 (anything else just gets me Fs).  However, with this configuration the processor is reading the response shifted 1 bit to the left. I'm suspecting the STM is trying to read the data on the rising edge and thus misses the MSB.

I found that if I set CPHA to 1 between writing the command and reading the response, I get my expected outcome, but only every other time I execute the whole transaction; otherwise I get Fs.  If I loop it I alternate between all Fs and the expected data.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Relevant code snippet:

```
  hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
  hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
  hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi3.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi3.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
  
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  
  static uint8_t cmd = 0x9F;
  
  while (1){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, &cmd, 1, 10000);
    //SPI3->CR1 &= ~(1<<6);
    //SPI3->CR1 |= 1;
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi3, buf, 5, 10000);
    printSpiBuf();
    //SPI3->CR1 &= ~(1<<6);
    //SPI3->CR1 &= ~1;     
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
```

Comment: It's best you mention which exact SPI flash chip it is, preferably with a link to datasheet. It is very rare that there are incompatibilities with SPI flash chips and MCUs with SPI interfaces, maybe you are doing something wrong here? It's also best to state which exact STM32F4 model it is.

Comment: Standard SPI flash chips and STM32 support updating the data wire on falling edge, so that they both latch the stable data on rising edge. If this does not work, you must post schematics and code to figure out where the error is.

Comment: The flash chip is SST25VF064C and the MCU is STM32F401RE.

Comment: These are compatible. Post your schematics and code to find any errors.

Comment: Compare the diagram on page 5 of the [SST25VF064C datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005036C.pdf) with the diagram on page 565 of the [STM32F401 reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0368-stm32f401xbc-and-stm32f401xde-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). Looks to me as though either [CPOL=0, CPHA=0] or[ CPOL=1, CPHA=1] should work. The STM *should* be trying to read data on the clock rising edge - that's when it's stable, because the Flash changes to the next bit on the falling edge.

Comment: Bizarrely, neither of those configurations work although I agree that from the diagrams they should.  The _only_ combination that elicits a response from the flash is [CPOL=1, CPHA=0].  Adding code to the original post.

Comment: The commented register access lines will cause the MCU to read the expected data from the chip, but only on every other loop.